# Compare 2 tables (TABLE_A vs TABLE_B) in Oracle 11g to find difference between them, Facing issue to do 1 to many mapping for INSERT in single query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Compare 2 tables (TABLE_A vs TABLE_B)  in Oracle 11g  to find difference between them, Facing issue to do 1 to many mapping for INSERT in single query. Where same product has to be inserted multiple times in each Order where PRODUCT_TYPE_ID matches

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE_A" 
   (    "PRODUCT_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "PRODUCT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
   )

CREATE TABLE "TABLE_B" 
   (    "ORDER_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "PRODUCT_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "PRODUCT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
   )   



Insert into TABLE_A (PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (8,'HardCopy',4101,'Paths of glory');
Insert into TABLE_A (PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (8,'HardCopy',4102,'Atlas shrugged - Ayn Rand');
Insert into TABLE_A (PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (9,'Electronic',4201,'NY times');
Insert into TABLE_A (PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (9,'HardCopy',4202,'Wallstreet Journal');
Insert into TABLE_A (PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (8,'Electronic',4103,'War and Peace - Leo Tolstoy');


Insert into TABLE_B (ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (100,8,'Electronic',4107,'Zen Begineers mind');
Insert into TABLE_B (ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (100,8,'HardCopy',4101,'paths of glory');
Insert into TABLE_B (ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (100,8,'HardCopy',4102,'Atlas shrugged - Ayn Rand');
Insert into TABLE_B (ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (100,9,'HardCopy',4211,'Forbes');
Insert into TABLE_B (ORDER_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME) values (101,8,'Electronic',4111,'The Adventure of Hukleberry Finn ');


SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN t1.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL THEN 'DELETE'
    WHEN t2.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL then 'INSERT'
    WHEN t1.PRODUCT_ID is NOT NULL and t2.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL then 'UPDATE'     
END AS STATUS,
CASE
    WHEN t2.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL and t1.PRODUCT_ID is NOT NULL then t2.Order_id
    ELSE t2.Order_id
END AS Order_id,
CASE
    WHEN t1.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID IS NULL THEN t2.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
    ELSE t1.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
END AS PRODUCT_TYPE_ID ,
CASE
    WHEN t1.PRODUCT_TYPE IS NULL THEN t2.PRODUCT_TYPE
    ELSE t1.PRODUCT_TYPE
END AS PRODUCT_TYPE, 
CASE
    WHEN t1.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL THEN t2.PRODUCT_ID
    ELSE t1.PRODUCT_ID
END AS PRODUCT_ID,
CASE
    WHEN t1.PRODUCT_NAME IS  NULL THEN t2.PRODUCT_NAME
    ELSE t1.PRODUCT_NAME
END AS PRODUCT_NAME
FROM table_A t1
FULL JOIN table_B t2 on t1.PRODUCT_ID = t2.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE 1 in (decode(t1.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,t2.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID,0,1), decode(t1.PRODUCT_TYPE,t2.PRODUCT_TYPE,0,1),
decode(t1.PRODUCT_ID,t2.PRODUCT_ID,0,1),decode(t1.PRODUCT_NAME,t2.PRODUCT_NAME,0,1));
```

Expected Output -

```
STATUS  ORderId Product_type_id Product_type    Product_Id     Product_name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELETE  100     8               Electronic      4107           Zen Begineers mind
UPDATE  100     8               HardCopy         4101          Paths of glory
DELETE  100     9               HardCopy        4211           Forbes
INSERT  100     9               Electronic      4201           NY times
INSERT  100     9               HardCopy        4202           Wallstreet Journal

DELETE  101     8               Electronic      4111           The Adventure of Hukleberry Finn 
INSERT  101     8               Electronic      4103           War and Peace - Leo Tolstoy        
INSERT  101     8               HardCopy        4101           Paths of glory
INSERT  101     8               HardCopy        4102           Atlas shrugged - Ayn Rand
```

TABLE_A is product catalogue that gets refreshed End of day
Row with PRODUCT_ID can be modified, data in any column against it can be updated ( e.g change in Product_name),
a new product_id could be added or existing product_id could be deleted.
All product_id belong to certain type ie. Product_type_ID, so if there are 2 entries in TABLE_A now, it can increase or shrink tomorrow (never 0)
Modification in TABLE_A is not in our control

TABLE_B is Orders data. At day end, need to sync product info in TABLE_B with latest data from TABLE_A.
We can identify relation, based on table_A.product_id = table_B.product_id.
One Order_ID can have multiple PRODUCT_TYPE_IDs and that PRODUCT_TYPE_ID in turn can have multiple PRODUCT_IDs.

Eg
In TABLE_B, Order_id = 101  has PRODUCT_TYPE_ID=8. On comparison table_A.product_id = table_B.product_id existing record in TABLE_B has to be marked DELETE, as it's not in TABLE_A
As Order_id = 101 has PRODUCT_TYPE_ID =8, we've to look up TABLE_A with PRODUCT_TYPE_ID=8 and bring in latest data into TABLE_B thus making 3 INSERTS (3 rows in TABLE_A for PRODUCT_TYPE_ID=8)
this has to be done for all Order_IDs with PRODUCT_TYPE_ID =8, like Order_id=100
Thus 1 set of records from TABLE_A needs to be INSERTed multiple times in every Order_ID where PRODUCT_TYPE_ID matches

Use PRODUCT_ID to join and do comparison what matches and what doesn't --> I've used it to evaluate DELETE and UPDATE (above query)
Use PRODUCT_TYPE_ID to find out which all Order_IDs needs INSERT ---> struggling to do  1 to many mapping

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the expected output ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do you know the relationship between order_id and product_id for rows where there is no match ? Eg how do you know to take order_id 100  for product 4201 and 101 for 4103 ?

Comment: Thanks @Sujitmohanty30 for your response, I've update my question explaining it a bit thanks for your response

Comment: @GarethD I've update my question explaining it a bit, I hope I'm able to convey my question. Thanks for your curiosity towards my query.

Comment: @KoenLostrie, Thanks for response I've updated my query with further explanation, I hope I'm clear.

Comment: @Rishi18, Do you want to fix your query ? or Do you want to have logic which does all insert/update/delete ? and One more question regarding `update` only change can happen to  `Product_name` as i see in the given sample data. am I right ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie It's based on product_type_id, 1 order can have multiple product_type_id.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30  looking for  query that'll do all insert/update/delete, is it possible to do it in single query ? or need to use Cursor to compare all records, there are  ~20k records in TABLE_A and ~500k records in TABLE_B ? will there be performance implication with Cursors on this kind of data ?... change can happen in any of the column thus I'm using decode in all columns

Comment: All columns can be changed but not `Product_type_id` or `Product_Id`. right ? Don't know if possible within one query and particularly with `delete`. For such number of data it should not be a problem with respect to performance if basic indexes are available. Bulk operations could be handy hare as well. If I have to give it a try needs time from myside but If I have anything I will update and till then if you got any answer would be good as well. Cheers !!